# How to check expiry of access token and send refresh token

Tags: react-native, fetch, access-token, refresh-token

I am making an app without login i have successfully fetched access token and used it for authentication of another api. But now i want to check expiry of the access token and if the access token is expired how to send refresh token

i found refreshableFetch but i do not know should i use it or not because it not uses refresh token

```
fetch('URL', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
               etc...
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState({data: responseData})
            })
```

I am fetching the data as regular. Please suggest me methods to check expiry of access token and to use refresh token

Comment: You may check token expiry on api end  & send response like { status: false , message: "token expired" }

Comment: thanks for reply but how to check expiry of token in my app

Comment: are you using your own apis or some 3rd party ?

Comment: i am using my own api and in that expiry is 36000

Comment: you can store date with each token field and check the difference between incoming request time to your token creation time in db and follow steps as per my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you the flow of how you can achieve your desire goal

- fetch access token
- send access token with every request after that.
- check on server end for expiry of each incoming request token.
- if token has expired (I assume you have a date in your db) send  `{ status: false , message: "token expired" }` else  `{ status: true,
  data: "YOUR DATA", message: "" }`
- check for status on client end, if status is `false` && message is `token expire` call refresh token api
- In refresh token api, update new token on server

I tried to explain you the flow as I am unaware of your backend logic and code. Hope you can modify the code accordingly as you get the gist :)